# Ошибка при настройке FTP-сервера через командную строку

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, ftp

Необходимо создать FTP-сервер средствами командной строки, но при запуске команд возникает ошибка.
Ошибка следующая: ошибка конфигурации
Описание: Не удалось прочитать файл конфигурации из-за отсутствия необходимых разрешений

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
set ftproot=%systemdrive%\inetpub\ftproot
set ftpsite=MyFtp
if not exist "%ftproot%" (mkdir "%ftproot%") 
appcmd add site /name:%ftpsite% /bindings:ftp://*:21 /physicalpath:"%ftproot%" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.authentication.AnonimouseAuthentication.enabled:true
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy:"SslAllow" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy:"SslAllow" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.directoryBrowse.showFlags:DisplayVirtualDirectories 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.userIsolation.mode:StartInUsersDirectory 
appcmd set config %ftpsite% /section:system.ftpserver/security/authorization /+[accessType='Allow',permissions='Read',roles='',users='*'] /commit:apphost
```

Какие действия следует предпринять чтобы устранить данную проблему?

Comment: Какая у вас операционная система, и что за сервер?

Comment: OC Windows 10, сервер локальный

Comment: к сожалению, не работал с Windows, только с Linux. Поэтому вряд ли чем смогу помочь. Извините